# Find all links with specific domain in the text with regex

Tags: regex

I have a text with links inside, so I try to match them with regex, but somehow the last step I miss..

Link to regex - https://regex101.com/r/pXzZvA/1

The text:

```
Some text with many letters and some kind of bla bla text
With links - -https://sub.mydomain.com/products/art-for-selling-1   - another word

-https://sub.mydomain.com/products/art-for-selling-1 
https://sub.mydomain.com/products/art-for-selling-1 

paf paf

pew pew 

sub.mydomain.com/products/art-for-selling-1
```

Here is the regex I use:

```
/(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^\.]+\.)?sub.mydomain.com(\/.*)$/gm
```

What do I miss is with all the matches I have match of "https://sub.mydomain.com/products/art-for-selling-1   - another word" with "   - another word" together. I need to add space exclusion to the end of the regex.

Comment: Do you mean you need `(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^.]+\.)?sub\.mydomain\.com(\/\S*)(?:\s.*)?`? Like in https://regex101.com/r/pXzZvA/2? What output do you expect?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this will match `   - another word` and one extra space after the link

Comment: @AhmedEl-Tabarani But won't capture that. It all depends how the regex is used and what is necessary to consume here.

Comment: oh, I got it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use: `(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:\w+\.)?sub\.mydomain\.com\/(?:\w+-?\/?)+`

`(?:https?:\/\/)` : contain https:// or not (http or https)

`(?:\w+\.)?` : contain a `word` follow by `.` or not

`sub\.mydomain\.com\/` : must contain `sub.mydomain.com/`

`(?:\w+-?\/?)+` : contain many forms of `abc/abc/abc/.../...` or not (and may be contained a `-` after the `word` or not)